Preserve Line Breaks from EditText when Printing with Canvas - Kotlin Android Studio
I'm taking in a multiline EditText and storing the value into a variable. I then need to print this using Canvas. I know how to do text wrapping within Canvas, but the issue I'm having is that if the user presses enter when entering text into the EditText, this isn't preserved when storing it to a variable, and therefore when printing with Canvas.
For example, if the user enters:
1
2
3

It is printing as:
1 2 3

I've tried the following, but it just prints:
findingsComp = binding.findings.text.toString().replace("\\n".toRegex(), "<br />")

1<br /> 2<br /> 3<br />


Does this answer your question? Draw multi-line text to Canvas

@Leviathan this helped, thank you. I didn't know that you could use split with "\n" - thank you!

Per the link @Leviathan shared, I ended up creating a List of the lines and then iterating through the list to print it.
var findingText = myFragment.findingsComp.split("\n")
    var findingsY = 180F
    findingText.forEach {
        canvas.drawText(it, 36F, findingsY, body)
        findingsY = findingsY + 15F
    }

